# Saving multiple belongsToMany associations in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

**First let me explain what I'm trying to achieve.**

3 MySQL tables are relevant to this question:

presets:

```
id | name | description | user_id | ...
```

files:

```
id | name | size | ...
```

files_presets

```
id | file_id | preset_id | original_image (bool) | small_thumb (bool) | big_thumb (bool) | file (bool)
```

There is a form on this website that I'm building that is meant to create Presets.
A Preset is is composed of:

- 3 images: one original_image, one small_thumb and one big_thumb, all store in the `files` table
- An unknown number of files, also stored in the `files` table
- Additional information stored in the `presets` table

All files are uploaded via AJAX beforehand, so when the form is submitted all files are already in the database, and their IDs are sent via hidden input alongside all preset information.

The `files_presets` table is what I use to link each Preset to its files and images. The columns original_image, small_thumb, big_thumb and file are booleans that indicate what each file means to the preset.

So, this is how I defined my associations in the `PresetsTable.php` file:

```
    $this->belongsToMany('OriginalImage', [
        'through' => 'FilesPresets',
        'className' => 'Files',
        'property_name' => 'original_image',
        'foreignKey' => 'preset_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'file_id',
        'conditions' => ['FilesPresets.original_image' => true]
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('SmallThumb', [
        'through' => 'FilesPresets',
        'className' => 'Files',
        'property_name' => 'small_thumb',
        'foreignKey' => 'preset_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'file_id',
        'conditions' => ['FilesPresets.small_thumb' => true]
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('BigThumb', [
        'through' => 'FilesPresets',
        'className' => 'Files',
        'property_name' => 'big_thumb',
        'foreignKey' => 'preset_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'file_id',
        'conditions' => ['FilesPresets.big_thumb' => true]
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('Files', [
        'through' => 'FilesPresets',
        'className' => 'Files',
        'property_name' => 'files',
        'foreignKey' => 'preset_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'file_id',
        'conditions' => ['FilesPresets.file' => true]
    ]);
```

This way I can fetch all images and files associated to a preset doing something like this (not having any problems here):

```
    $preset = $this->Presets->get($id, [
        'contain' => [
            'OriginalImage', 'SmallThumb', 'BigThumb', 'Files'
        ]
    ]);
```

**The problem is:**

I get all sorts of errors when trying to save this data.

What I need to do:

- Save all the basic information to the `presets` table (name, description, etc)
- Create a record in the `files_presets` table for each one of the files, linking them to this preset that was just created while also saving other information (the boolean columns)

Keep in mind that I don't want to create new records to the `files` table, as files are already in the database and I have their IDs. I just want to associate their IDs with the new preset.

Thanks in advance for helping me,
Daniel.

Comment: You've exaplained it all nice and stuff, but the most important thing, the actual errors and the code used for saving are missing.

Comment: Hey Daniel, did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to try is using the alias name instead of the className:

```
$this->belongsToMany('OriginalImage', [
    'through' => 'FilesPresets',
    'className' => 'Files',
    'property_name' => 'original_image',
    'foreignKey' => 'preset_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'file_id',
    'conditions' => ['OriginalImage.original_image' => true] // <-- Changed `FilePresets` to `OriginalImage` alias.
]);
```

When Cake generates the SQL, it uses the alias instead of the underlying className in order to avoid conflicts between multiple associations to the same target table.